# Locking on condition and specific value

Tags: java, multithreading

I've started reading `Java concurrency in practice`, but before going on I have this thought that needs to be solved.

Take this code for example.
I've used Guava ([Striped](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html)) to retrive `Lock`(s).
And btw, I understand that, as stated by the Guava documentation, this is similar to using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
public Object getValue(final String input) {
   final Lock inputLock = STRIPED.get(input);

   try {
      inputLock.lock();
      Object value = VALUES.get(input);

      if (value == null) {
         value = buildValue(input);
         VALUES.put(input, value);
      }

      return value;
   } finally {
      inputLock.unlock();
   }
}
```

Now, this works by locking based on the input value.
However, if the `getValue(...)` method is called for the majority of times with the same value, I'm synchronizing for nothing, as synchronization is needed only for the first and only write.

How would you procede to optimize this piece of code (if possible)?

Comment: I'm no Guava expert, but usually you'd accomplish this by some form of double checked locking (so long as `VALUES` is marked as volatile.) You'd first call `VALUES.get()`, then if that returned null, obtain a lock, then make the same call again from within that lock. If that call also returned null, you could go ahead, build the value, then insert it into the map before releasing the lock again.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Oh Guava doesn't matter that much here. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Why are you using STRIPED? You can achieve the same using ConcurrentHashMap computeIfAbsent method

Comment: @NeeravVadodaria This is only for studying purposes. As I stated I know I could use ConcurrentHashMap, but wanted to know what a possible optimization could be

Comment: @MichaelBerry Looking for "double checked locking" on the Goetz book, he states it is an anti-pattern to avoid. So I think this code cannot be optimized without completely switching strategy.

Comment: @LppEdd Partly that's because it's *usually* a premature optimisation (as it may be in this case, but you're just talking theoretically.) I've almost never had to use it in practice. However, it's also historical - when that book came out, Java 5 had only just been released - and double checked locking was completely broken in Java 4 and earlier, so the chances of your code not doing what you think it did on a still-supported Java version were rather high (and with no easy way to check the incorrect behaviour on Java 4.) Fast forward to 2018, and we don't really have to worry about Java 4 :-)

Comment: @MichaelBerry yeah, no more Java 4 hahaha (but I'm still developing over Java 6, just to say it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn about locking, then you're on the right track.

If you want to actually use this in a critical application, you'd better use a standard implementation of this pattern, for example Guava's LoadingCache, which reuses the double locking logic of ConcurrentHashMap, but also allows to calculate a value in a thread safe way.

See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Even if you don't need the eviction logic, this is still a good solution for a thread-safe lazy calculation cache.

Comment: This might be useful especially to someone who is using a version of Java older then 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you are trying to achieve can be done using ConcurrentHashMap in Java 8.

```
public Object getValue(final String input) {
    return chm.computeIfAbsent(input, ip -> buildValue(ip));
}
```

Comment: Hi! Worth mentioning it is only for Java 8+ users.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lock for those existed values, just move `VALUES.get` out of the locked section. Then check `value` again when you lock.

```
public Object getValue(final String input) {
    Object value = VALUES.get(input);
    if (value == null) {
        Lock lock = STRIPED.get(input);
        try {
            lock.lock();
            value = VALUES.get(input);
            if (value == null) {
                value = buildValue(input);
                VALUES.put(input, value);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: This becomes a little bit "weird" to look at, but if it's the only way, then it's ok.

Comment: @LppEdd I don't know if there are other ways. More about this method you can checkout http://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton-double-checked-locking.

Comment: I usually go fo the lazy class initialization method for singletons. It's less verbose and redundant.

Comment: If it comes with multi-threading, there are always something verbose.

Comment: The thing I don't like the most is the double Map#get call. It might become an heavy operation.

Comment: @LppEdd This only happens when you first get some keys or those threads which are accidentally simultaneously get the same key for the first time.

Comment: Anyway, you have to check if ```input``` is existed after you lock, but you also have to get the value before you lock for more efficiency. So called double check.